# Sublime Text Insert Guid

Tags: guid, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I've started using Sublime Text and it's great. But while editing Wix setup files I need to insert randomly generated GUID's in form like `52E47764-B722-4E8A-9BA8-DDA5B1500391`.

The question: is there any snippet or hotkey or something else to insert GUID to text beeing edited

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a plugin for it: https://github.com/SublimeText/GenerateUUID